# Need to know the specific shipping method code for UPS Standard within Shopify's API

Tags: api, shopify, ups

I have an urgent need to know the specific code for UPS Standard shipping within Shopify's API. It would be a 2-digit number found in the Order API, shipping-lines > shipping-line > code.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: For instance, UPS Next Day is 01, UPS 2nd Day is 02, UPS Ground is 03, UPS 3-Day is 07, and UPS International is 65. I need the code for UPS Standard. Thx!

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use case? This field is a string, and at a glance, the contents are fairly reliably just text.

Comment: I'm less concerned about the cast of the field (string vs int) as I am the actual content. I need to know what 2-digit/character string/number represents UPS Standard in the shipping-lines->shipping-line->code field. Our fulfillment house's API uses a different set of codes to represent various shipping methods, so we have a look-up table that pairs the values from Shopify's API to those of the fulfillment house's API in order for the fulfillment house to know the proper shipping method to use.

Comment: I'm looking at results in the database for the 'code' field where title is USPS Standard, and the contents aren't numeric. This seems to be neither something that we store, nor something that can reliably be pulled from shipping_lines.

Comment: But we're pulling those contents from other orders reliably. I don't care if they're numeric or alpha -- I just need to know the value contained in that field for UPS Standard.

Comment: In other words: is there something in the "code" field for "UPS Standard?" If the answer is "yes," then what is in the field?

Comment: It looks like it's also "USPS Standard", some records are lower-case.

Comment: Lydia, is there another way to contact you? StackOverflow is griping at me about extended discussions in comments and I don't have a high enough reputation to move it to chat. But I still have more questions about this. Thanks.

Comment: Please email me at lydia at shopify.

Answer (score 8):

UPS Standart code value is '11'

Also some other UPS codes:

```
'01' => 'Next Day Air ("Red")',
'02' => 'Second Day Air ("Blue")',
'03' => 'Ground',
'07' => 'Express',
'08' => 'Expedited', 
'11' => 'Standard',
'12' => 'Third Day Select',
'13' => 'Next Day Air Saver ("Red Saver")',
'14' => 'Next Day Air Early A.M.',
'15' => 'Next Day Air Early A.M.',
'22' => 'Ground - Returns Plus - Three Pickup Attempts',
'32' => 'Next Day Air Early A.M. - COD',
'33' => 'Next Day Air Early A.M. - Saturday Delivery, COD',
'41' => 'Next Day Air Early A.M. - Saturday Delivery',
'42' => 'Ground - Signature Required',
'44' => 'Next Day Air - Saturday Delivery',
'54' => 'Express Plus',
'59' => 'Second Day Air A.M.',
'65' => 'WorldWide Saver',
'66' => 'Worldwide Express',
'72' => 'Ground - Collect on Delivery',
'78' => 'Ground - Returns Plus - One Pickup Attempt',
'90' => 'Ground - Returns - UPS Prints and Mails Label',
'A0' => 'Next Day Air Early A.M. - Adult Signature Required',
'A1' => 'Next Day Air Early A.M. - Saturday Delivery, Adult Signature Required',
'A2' => 'Next Day Air - Adult Signature Required',
'A8' => 'Ground - Adult Signature Required',
'A9' => 'Next Day Air Early A.M. - Adult Signature Required, COD',
'AA' => 'Next Day Air Early A.M. - Saturday Delivery, Adult Signature Required, COD',
```

Comment: Where did you get this from?

Comment: @cjbarth, sorry, it was one year ago, I do not remember.

Comment: You can find the codes in the UPS Developer Kit https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit (at the time of this post, page 29 in "Rating Package - Web Services Developers Guide.pdf")

Answer (score 2):

If you download the UPS shipping developer documentation, there are no longer any codes for 'Saturday' delivery in the Appendix or elsewhere. Instead you use the service you want, say 'Next Day Air' or 'Next Day Air Early AM' would be the common ones along with the `SaturdayDeliveryIndicator`. From their documentation:

> Saturday delivery indicator. The presence indicates Saturday delivery;
>   the absence indicates not Saturday delivery.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways:

1. in magento admin go to system > configuration and click on shipping methods tab and rightclick inside of the Allowed Methods box, Inpect the element and you'll see something like UPS Standard value represents the method code.
2. or open app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php and around the line 327 you will see all shipping methods with corresponding codes.